# How to control ESX VM via C#?

Tags: c#, esx

I am trying to control my virtual machines by C#. 
Using ESX 5.5 and windows 7 
I found these 2 wrappers:

- [VMWareTasks](https://github.com/dblock/vmwaretasks)
- [vixcomwrapper](http://vixcomwrapper.codeplex.com/)

With both `DLL`s I can connect to the ESX server and power on my machine.
But after power on, the code gets stuck and I can't continue.
There is any other solution to control ESX machine ?

When I try to control a VM workstation I don't have any issues, so my real problem is with ESX server.
Huge thanks for helpers.

**Edit**

```
using (VMWareVirtualHost virtualHost = new VMWareVirtualHost())
{
virtualHost.ConnectToVMWareVIServer("1.1.1.1", "root", "password");
using (VMWareVirtualMachine virtualMachine = virtualHost.Open(@"[Compellent_External_] yosia_win7_1/yosia.vmx"))
{
virtualMachine.PowerOn();
virtualMachine.WaitForToolsInGuest();
virtualMachine.LoginInGuest("user", "password");
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in the future by yourselft. Thanks

Comment: I have never tried anything like this, but you are waiting for tools in guest. Are the tools installed in your guest VM?

Comment: Thanks Jonny , i forgot to install the tools manually . now all works